# Java Applet Game

Tags: java, if-statement

I have started making a java applet for a game like battleships.  Here is what I am trying to do:

Builds a 10x10 board, randomly picking 10 coordinates on which 'ships' are located. The user guesses ship locations by clicking on the board, placing white pegs for a 'miss', and red pegs for a 'hit'.
As soon as the user hits the last 'ship' the program writes a winning message including the number of guesses it took and exits.

I have made the 10x10 board and have stored the random locations of the reg pegs in an ArrayList. Right now, it allows outputs the coordinates of the hidden red dots for me to test, and places them when they are hit. If it doesn't hit, it allows me to put a white dot. How would I make it count how many hits it take and at the end if all is filled or all 10 ships are found, get it to output game over and amount of hits? Any help is appreciated and thank you. Here is a section of my code:

```
 Boolean isHit = false;

 while(unWon && totalClicks <= 100) {
 isHit = false; // reset isHit
 Coordinate currentClick = board.getClick(); // Get the current click

 //Check the ship coordinates to see whether it is hit
 for(Coordinate c: ships) {
   if(c.getRow() == currentClick.getRow() && c.getCol() == currentClick.getCol()) {
     board.putPeg("red", currentClick.getRow(), currentClick.getCol());
     isHit = true;
     break;          
   }
 }

 // If it didn't hit, mark it with a white peg
 if (!isHit) {
   board.putPeg("white", currentClick.getRow(), currentClick.getCol());
    } 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your content. Once it is posted to the site, it is licensed to the site and 'belongs to the community'.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two separate loops over `ships` in this code for some reason:

```
for(Coordinate c: ships){
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
```

Get rid of the outer one. It's not doing anything useful, and the `if` statements related to it are making all the code "inside" that loop get skipped if `currentClick` is not on a location in `ships`.

Comment: So what would that section of code look like after edited? What do I need to change with the if statements?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need a little bit of cleanup to make things easier to sort through:

```
// This will be used to track whether any of the ship coordinates is a match for currentClick
Boolean isHit = false;

// It looks like you can combine these two conditions, but if that changes, just put `totalClicks <= 100` in its own `if` statement
while(unWon && totalClicks <= 100) {
  // reset isHit
  isHit = false;
  // Get the current click
  Coordinate currentClick = board.getClick();
  // Check the ship coordinates to see whether we hit
  for(Coordinate c: ships) {
    if(c.getRow() == currentClick.getRow() && c.getCol() == currentClick.getCol()) {
      board.putPeg("red", currentClick.getRow(), currentClick.getCol());
      isHit = true;
      break;          
    }
  }
  // If we didn't hit, mark it with white
  if (!isHit) {
    board.putPeg("white", currentClick.getRow(), currentClick.getCol());
  } 
}
```

To improve the clarity, you could put the red check into its own function:

```
Boolean isHit(Coordinate currentClick, ArrayList<Coordinate> ships) {
  for(Coordinate c: ships) {
    if(c.getRow() == currentClick.getRow() && c.getCol() ==  currentClick.getCol()) {
    return = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then you can get rid of the isHit boolean and rewrite your while:

```
while(unWon && totalClicks <= 100) {
  Coordinate currentClick = board.getClick();
  if (isHit(currentClick, ships)) {
    board.putPeg("red", currentClick.getRow(), currentClick.getCol());
  } else {
    board.putPeg("white", currentClick.getRow(), currentClick.getCol());
  }
}
```

Comment: The first part worked but what do you mean by improving the clarity. I don't quite understand what you did in the second and third sections. Thanks for your help as it is now allowing me to click the white dots.

Comment: The second section splits out the test for whether the current click is a hit into its own function which allows you to simply the while loop as the third section.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for your help! @adamdc78